# Programing language for windows without downloading?

Tags: windows, windows-10

**I am looking for a programming language or framework to run scripts in windows without having to download anything**

I am sort of new to programming, I have mostly programmed in python using VSCode, and also in C# using Unity. I want to be able to transfer a script in a language to a windows computer, where I do not need to install anything in the other computer to run it. Python does not work for this because you need to download python. C# with .NET does not work because you need to download .NET and do some editing with admin privileges. What language and framework is already installed and done in windows?

Comment: [Windows Script Host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2003/cc784547(v=ws.10)) maybe.

Comment: .NET comes by default in Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Batch files
- VBScript and JScript ([Windows Scripting Host](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Script_Host)) [Win98+]
- [MSHTA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_Application) [Win2000+?]
- Command line C# compiler included with Windows (csc.exe in one of the .NET framework folders in the Windows directory) [WinVista+ or .NET installed on 2000/XP]
- PowerShell [Win7+ or installed on XP/Vista]

Comment: https://www.guru99.com/powershell-tutorial.html